How to fix Unresolved references
build.gradle.kts(:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.testapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.testapp"
        minSdk = 31
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

Unresolved references:

I created another project without experiencing any problems. How can I fix the above errors?
UPDATE :
output after fixing above error
it is working and not working at the same time
the project is initiated but terminated without any output.
interface shows app_name keeps stopping

Try applying plugins like in https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/blob/master/samples/hello-android/app/build.gradle.kts

@jokuskay; Do you suggest that they should switch back from versions catalogs? Why shouldn't their problem be fixable with version catalogs?

@Shubham GAUTAM: Have you tried re-synching your gradle files (with CTRL+SHIFT+O, for example)? What errors does this output? Can you update your question with this new information?

@Leviathan . i've updated the question with output it's working and not working at the same time

Does this answer your question? Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?
